# Implementing auto completion in Java

Tags: java, search, autocomplete

[image]

I was working on creating a weather application in Java using Weather Underground and I found that it does have data for some cities.

Initially, I was planning on using `GeopIP` to get the user's location automatically but since the support for cities is limited I decided to let the user choose the city every time the program starts.

I want the user to be able to choose a city from one that is supported by Weather Underground. The user will enter the name and as he/she enters the name, the possible locations will be displayed in a way similar to the one shown in the picture.

My question is:

How do I implement this **search** feature ?

My initial guess was to create a `Vector` containing all the names of the cities and then use brute force to find the match and display in a `JPopup` or a `JWindow containing a JList` but I guess there has to be a better method

### Rephrase:

What I do not understand is **WHAT INFO** do I keep in the data structure I must use ? Should I manually create a list of cities that `Weather Underground` supports or is there another way to do it ?

Comment: No, that's pretty much exactly how you do it (with the exception of don't use `Vector`s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918 (among numerous others)

Comment: Concrete code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476223/windows-application-with-auto-complete-using-tab-of-unix-machine-files-and-direc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you google [autosuggestcombobox](https://www.google.de/search?q=autosuggestcombobox) you will get some interesting results:

[This](http://code.google.com/p/javafx-demos/source/browse/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/java/com/ezest/javafx/components/javafxcombobox/AutoSuggestComboBox.java?r=44) one is written in JavaFX - I have used and extended it myself already. It is quite useful. What you get "for free" with JavaFX: a context menu with right-mouse click which is auto-generated containing some of the usual "stuff", like cut, copy & paste and even undo! So, I can recommend that solution. To get into JavaFX isn't so hard - and I think it is much easier to learn than Swing - and looks so much cooler! However this implementation has some drawbacks - especially when the layout is not left-aligned, because it is simply a text field on top of a combobox.

OK - but if you want to stick to Swing - you could probably use [this one](http://smi-protege.stanford.edu/repos/protege/bioportal-reference-plugin/trunk/src/edu/stanford/bmir/protegex/bp/importing/AutoSuggestComboBox.java). I haven't used that myself, but the code looks quite straightforward and pretty clean - cleaner than the implementation for JavaFX I must admit (but that had some nice features). So - maybe you try - and extend it? It is built simply on `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure (also known as digital tree or prefix tree). Autocompletion is one of the most common examples of it's usefulness.

The following article has a nice an very approachable explanation:

[Roll your own autocomplete solution using Tries.](http://v1v3kn.tumblr.com/post/18238156967/roll-your-own-autocomplete-solution-using-tries)